# Import product images with slash in the SKU

Tags: magmi

I need help with this problem:

I upload the articles on magento through Magmi v0.7.22 and associate the images to the product through the plugin "Value replacer", because sku and images have the same name: {item.sku}.jpg.

Until here everything is fine.

It happens that I have some sku with the character / (slash) in the sku, for example: 23df.124/rpo and obviously I can not give the same name to the image.

Can you give me a suggestion on how to solve this problem?
Thank you and apologise for my poor English.

Comment: if there is no problem in changing sku values, than replace `/` by '-' in a mass using excel sheet or notepad++....

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, I cannot change the item code. The associated images are named with a - instead of /. What I need is to know how to write a dynamic variable in order to be able to associate image with the article.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved with this regular expression:

```
{{preg_replace('/\/+/', '-', {item.sku})}}.jpg
```